# Show file upload speed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Is it possible to show for user upload speed?

I'm uploading file (video) to Firebase. File is so large (approx. 2GB).

Can I show for user currently upload speed for that file?

Comment: Speed or bytes uploaded?

Comment: Internet speed (upload) - bytes and progress I already show.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty similar to how you are showing the progress. If you are showing the progress that means you can access the `bytesTransferred` property. now you just need to calculate the speed by using that property. There could be a better or more optimized way to do this but this is how I do it.

```
int lastBytesTransferred = 0;
DateTime? lastBytesTransferredTime;

// to make sure the speed only updates once in an interval and not every millisecond or so
Duration updateDurationThreshold = const Duration(seconds: 2);

double speed = 0;

UploadTask task =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("files/$fileName").putData(file!);

task.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
  if (lastBytesTransferredTime == null) {
    lastBytesTransferred = event.bytesTransferred;
    lastBytesTransferredTime = DateTime.now();
    speed = 0;
  } else {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final Duration duration = now.difference(lastBytesTransferredTime!);
    if (duration > updateDurationThreshold) {
      final double bytesPerSecond =
          (event.bytesTransferred - lastBytesTransferred) /
              duration.inSeconds;
      lastBytesTransferred = event.bytesTransferred;
      lastBytesTransferredTime = now;
      setState(() {
        speed = bytesPerSecond / 1024; // in kbps
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDKs [report progress for file uploads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress) to Cloud Storage, which you can use to calculate the upload speed. In Flutter you can listen for upload events, as shown in the second code sample in the documentation on [handling upload tasks](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#handling-tasks). From there:

> for larger files it may be a better user experience if a progress indicator can be shown. Tasks can also provide a stream of events, which emits a [TaskSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/TaskSnapshot-class.html) each time a notable event occurs (e.g. upload progress). The snapshot provides information about the state of the task along with the amount of bytes that have been processed:
>
> ```
> Future<void> handleTaskExample2(String filePath) async {
>   File largeFile = File(filePath);
>
>   firebase_storage.UploadTask task = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
>       .ref('uploads/hello-world.txt')
>       .putFile(largeFile);
>
>   task.snapshotEvents.listen((firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
>     print('Task state: ${snapshot.state}');
>     print(
>         'Progress: ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100} %');
>   }, onError: (e) {
>     // The final snapshot is also available on the task via `.snapshot`,
>     // this can include 2 additional states, `TaskState.error` & `TaskState.canceled`
>     print(task.snapshot);
>
>     if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
>       print('User does not have permission to upload to this reference.');
>     }
>   });
>
>   // We can still optionally use the Future alongside the stream.
>   try {
>     await task;
>     print('Upload complete.');
>   } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
>     if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
>       print('User does not have permission to upload to this reference.');
>     }
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Of course I'm showing progress. Do you know how I can calculate internet speed to show it user?

Comment: You can calculate the remaining time with ( ( elapsed_time * file_size ) / bytes_uploaded ) - elapsed_time